# How to set up to make sure all data in API Management inside a region?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I want to create a new API Management instance in EU and make sure my data in APIM can not leaves the EU geographic zone

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Microsoft documentation, the data will not leave the configured region.

[Data residency in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/data-residency/#overview) provides you with information about the data based on selected regions:

[image]

> Most Azure services enable you to specify the region where your customer data will be stored and processed. Microsoft may replicate to other regions for data resiliency, but Microsoft will not store or process customer data outside the selected Geo. You and your users may move, copy, or access your customer data from any location globally.

Customers can configure the following Azure services, tiers, or plans to store customer data only in a single region:
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region

> Only the gateway component of API Management is deployed to all regions. The service management component and developer portal are hosted in the Primary region only.